# Nextjs: Loading or Suspense fallback won't show in production

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel, react-server-components

I've migrated my personal page to the app directoy with nextjs v13.

I was trying adding loaders for RSCs first in the `fallback` prop of the `Suspense` component and also adding a `loading` component located at path of each route from the `app` directory.

```
// src/app/posts/loading.tsx
import { Container } from '~/components/organisms/container';

export default function Loading() {
  return (
    <Container>
      {/* Add a big loading string with tailind */}
      <span className="text-6xl font-bold text-center text-red-500">Loading...</span>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

and also like this

```
// src/app/posts/page.tsx
export default async function PostsPage() {
  return (
    <Container>
      <PageHeader
        title='Posts'
        description="I love to write about things I'm learning. 
            Blogging is a great way to improve and share knowledge.
            And who knows, maybe one day it might help me to write a book!"
      />
      <Suspense
        fallback={
          <Container>
            {/* Add a big loading string with tailind */}
            <span className='text-6xl font-bold text-center text-red-500'>
              Loading...
            </span>
          </Container>
        }
      >
        {/* @ts-expect-error Server Component */}
        <Posts />
      </Suspense>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

both working in local development

[image: localhost-loaders]

however they are not shown in my vercel deployments

- Wrapping with `Suspense` the RSCs: [this url](https://fer-toasted.vercel.app/)
- Using the `loading.tsx` file: [this url](https://fer-toasted-site-git-next-loaders-no-skellie-esponges.vercel.app/)

I'm using node `18.16` locally and node `18.x` in my vercel deployment. I'm also using the default configuration for deploying nextjs projects in vercel.

The branch code can be found [here](https://github.com/esponges/fer-personal-site/tree/next-loaders-no-skellie/src/app/posts) in case anybody needs more details

Answer (score 0):

You don't include how you are loading the data, but if you are using the new `fetch` then it might have something to do with the [built-in caching that nextjs is doing](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching#static-data-fetching) -- it will cache data indefinitely by default. On production it just looks like your posts are loaded instantly

Answer (score 0):

That is because when deploying in vercel, it executes the production mode of your application, and in this mode the static html of each of your pages is automatically built, that is why you do not see the loading load. To solve this you would have to work the component as ""Client Component", assigned the "use client" directive at the top, and here you would work it as you would in react with Suspense and lazy. The disadvantage of this is that you will not have the static html of the component you are loading, which is good for SEO